# postcss-import grunt plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

Structure of my project is like this:

```
my_project
|-- css
|   -- main.css
|-- css-dev
|   -- main.css
|-- node_modules
|   -- bootstrap
|       -- dist
|           -- css
|               -- bootstrap.css
|-- package.json
`-- Gruntfile.js
```

And my `Gruntfile.js` is like this :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var processorArray = [
        require('postcss-import')(),
        require('cssnano')()
    ];
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        postcss: {
            options: {
                processors: processorArray
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'css-dev/',
                    src: ['**/*.css'],
                    dest: 'css/'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['css-dev/*.css'],
                tasks: ['postcss'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

};
```

As you see , I want to use [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/) Grunt plugin to import `bootstrap.css` file into `css-dev/main.css` file and minifying result and place final file in `css` directory as a `main.css` file name.

Content of `main.css` file in `css-dev` directory is :

```
@import "bootstrap.css";

/* normalize selectors */
h1::before, h1:before {
    /* reduce shorthand even further */
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    /* reduce color values */
    color: #ff0000;
    /* drop outdated vendor prefixes */
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    /* remove duplicated properties */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    /* reduce position values */
    background-position: bottom right;
}

/* correct invalid placement */
@charset "utf-8";

.test{
    font: 12px Calibri;
}
```

I think that all things are correct, but after running grunt tasks ,seems `@import` does not work properly and result file is like this :

```
@import "bootstrap.css";h1:before{margin:10px 20px;color:red;border-radius:16px;font-weight:400;background-position:100% 100%}.test{font:2px Calibri}
```

Means Unexpectedly, content of bootstrap file not imported to `main.css` file.

what is problem,how can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think postcss-import is finding your bootstrap css file, you can specify exactly where to look for it using the path property.

```
var processorArray = [
    require('postcss-import')({
        path: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'
    }),
    require('cssnano')()
];
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    postcss: {
        options: {
            processors: processorArray
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'css-dev/',
                src: ['**/*.css'],
                dest: 'css/'
            }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: ['css-dev/*.css'],
            tasks: ['postcss'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

It really depends how you're pulling your css libraries, i think your asking how would you set it up so they are found automatically. According to the plugin

> This plugin can consume local files, node modules or web_modules. To
>   resolve path of an @import rule, it can look into root directory (by
>   default process.cwd()), web_modules, node_modules or local modules.
>   When importing a module, it will looks for index.css or file
>   referenced in package.json in the style or main fields. You can also
>   provide manually multiples paths where to look at.

Meaning for your bootstrap css, if you leave the import as

```
@import "bootstrap.css";
```

The only place it looks automatically are

```
web_modules/bootstrap.css
node_modules/bootstrap.css
local_modules/bootstrap.css
```

If you change your import to

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

It will look in the following folders for index.css

```
web_modules/bootstrap/index.css
node_modules/bootstrap/index.css
local_modules/bootstrap/index.css
```

If you've pulled your css library using some kind of package manager and it has a package.json sat in the root folder of the library

```
node_modules/bootstrap/package.json
```

The package.json can tell postcss where to find the library using either the main or style property

```
{
    ...
    "main": "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
}
```

But like i said it really depends how you're pulling you're libraries, if you're just manually grabbing them and putting them in nested folders further than where the plugin looks, then you'll just have to add the direct paths to the file in the path object as shown in my original answer

Comment: your solution works, but your path is only for bootstrap but what about if I want to import other css libraries?

Comment: according to your guide , I user `@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" ;` to fetch bootstrap file automatically from `node_modules` directory.

Comment: That works as well but that's just the same as adding the path to the postcss-import. The upside of having the path in your config means that if you reuse that css component in another project your css isn't tied to your project structure, the config is.